# access an button inside a movieclip with dynamic name in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic

:)

I'm trying to access a some properties in as3 like

```
myMovieClip.myButton1.visible = false;
```

I have other buttons:
myButton1, myButton2, myButtonN

So, I'm trying to access with a for like

`

```
for( i = 1; i < isProfileActive.length; i++)
{
   myMovieClip.this["myButton" + i].visible = false;
}
```

`

but I can't :(

How can I do that?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myMovieClip["myButton" + i].visible = false;
```

Comment: OMG

It wooooooorrrkkkks :)  thank you very much, I've tried for a long time before to make the post, thanks a lot